# $gt not retrieving the currect values

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to perform this query

```
myColection.list(num)=>{
return value
    .find({"ATOMIC_WEIGHT":{$gt:num}}) 
    .exec()
}
```

but its not performing as it should. 
In the ATOMIC_WEIGHT field i got strings store as "205" and "74.5524" for example, but if i want to retrieve all documents where ATOMIC_WEIGHT is greater than 200 it works fine with strings where numbers are integer but where numbers are decimals it retrieves them too even if they are lower than 200.

See the image to understand better

https://i.stack.imgur.com/prtbI.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform greater than or less than query on strings. It is for numbers. If you perform the query on string then it will perform operation on basis of ascii value. Try this in browser console **'73.5555'<'200'**. It will return false. You need to store the atomic weight as a number in your db. That is the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This will may solve your problem

I also had a same problem 
If i give $gt Number type value, it can work, but String type value can't work.
`db.getCollection('user').count({balance:{ $gt:10}})`

> Finally, I used
>
> ```
> db.getCollection('user').count("this.balance > 10")
> ```

You can try

```
myColection.list(num)=>{
return value
    .find("this.ATOMIC_WEIGHT > 10) 
    .exec()
}
```